# SQL Fastest Way to Count Rows with Where Clause

Tags: sql-server, select, count

I am new to SQL Server, I experience a very slow retrieval in SQL Server from a large table.

Here is my query.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(reference) 
FROM 
    shipment_table 
WHERE
    status = 'A' 
    AND shipment_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
```

I do some research in google, I found this code but I don't know how to add a WHERE clause for this (*where status = 'A' and shipment_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31'*)

```
SELECT
    Total_Rows= SUM(st.row_count)
FROM
    sys.dm_db_partition_stats st
WHERE
    object_name(object_id) = 'shipment_table' AND (index_id < 2)
```

Thank you,

Comment: create an appropriate (filtered) index on status and shipment_date

Comment: Answers below point to the issue - the fastest query is the one that will use the indexes on the table in the best way.  Sql server typically only uses one index to answer a query.  So if it picks status index, and that's not very selective (e.g. there are tons of status A rows) that won't perform well.  If it picks ship date index and there are tons of rows in that year (hope for your business there are :) ) then that won't perform well.  Only way for it to perform well is if there is an index on both data points

Answer (score 0):

Try using **COUNT(*)** instead of **COUNT(reference)**. They might look like they are the same but they are not. **COUNT(column_name)** will **not include NULL** values. So, if you have a column that is nullable it will scan every row just to find what is NULL and what is not. **COUNT(*)** on the other hand will include nullable values, so it doesn't need to scan every row. It also leverages the cache when the table **ENGINE=MYISAM**.

Answer (score 0):

Since most of the record search will be of 'A'.Hope status is char(1) only

Create filtered index on status columns

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX XI_Status
ON shipment_table (Status)
WHERE Status= 'A'
```

Create another non clustered index Date column

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX XI_ShipDate
ON shipment_table (shipment_date)


SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.shipment_table 
where status = 'A' and shipment_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' 
and '2018-12-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Cluster Index on shipment_date if shipment_date field is like a value insert date, I mean always increasing with each new row

This will increase performance of reads with a given shipment_date range

Answer (score 0):

First of all create non cluster index on date field and cluster index on primary key column, then you can use below query will be faster than previous one.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(primaryKeyColumn) 
FROM 
    shipment_table 
WHERE
    status = 'A' 
    AND shipment_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
```